# How to dokerize a cpanel worpress app based on the backup

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, backup, cpanel

I've been working with a hosting platform that uses cPanel. While I've managed to import the database successfully (as confirmed through phpMyAdmin), I can't access the original site. Instead, I only see the default WordPress interface. Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xxxx
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xxxx
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: xxxx
    volumes:
      - back:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxx
      MYSQL_USER: xxxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      #- ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
      #- ./usefulsarl_wp.sql.gz:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.sql.gz
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
    - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: 'xxxx'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxxx'
volumes:
  back:
  mysql:
```

I have tried to import the whole backup as volume. After that i have tried the homedir as volume and finally the wp-content as volume but nothing seems to work. I have also tryed codes availiable on github with out success..

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff you have to do to your WordPress database backup before it will work on a new host. Use a migration plugin. I like Duplicator but there are others. Run its installer.php in your containerized environment.